# Rails3 getting 'Could not dump table "table_name" because of following StandardError' error in the schema.rb file for the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

[image]

#Could not dump table "table_name" because of following StandardError
#Unknown type 'json' for column 'column_name'

Comment: Paste text errors instead of pictures

Comment: `json` columns were not implemented in rails 3, not sure what you are trying to do, or what database you are using, so this is the best answer I can offer. Essentially if you are using a json column you will have to upgrade rails, what version will depend on what database you are using.

Comment: i am using mysql:5.7 database

Comment: Edit your question with new information -- don't add in comments

Comment: I believe json columns for mysql was implemented in 5.2 (possibly 5.0) so you would need to update the rails application to atleast that version to appropriately support this data type in rails